# How can I draw arc like this image below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I won't make some of this arcs on my website and I don know how to do it I tried to do it but I can't !

#### Referance Image

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe give a better example

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Thank you next time I will more specific and give more example fo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a before/after pseudo element on one of the blocks. Then on that element you'd give it the same background color and use `transform: skew(-2deg);` to give it the tilted affect.

See the example below, it's fairly simple enough once you understand how you can use pseudo elements to your advantage.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 300px;
}

.skewedSection {
  background: red;
}

.normalSection:before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-2deg);
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  z-index: 2;

}
```

```html
<section class='normalSection'>
</section>

<section class='skewedSection'>
</section>
```